# access to variable from main file in a module that is called from app.get callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

in my app.js file I would have something like

`var obj = {one : 1}`

then I would do something like this in the app.js file:

`app.get("/index", middleware, require("./mymodule"))`

in my module I would do something like

```
module.exports = function(req, res){

but how would I access the variable obj from the main file

}
```

EDIT : I like having app.get in the main file so one solution pattern is like this:

```
app.get("/reviewfor/:comp", checkIfAuthed, function(req, res){
    require("./reviewforHandler")(req, res, obj);
})
```

but I wanted to do like above.

Another solution is to do `module.exports.obj` in the main file but it's weird doing module.exports from your main route file. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var obj = require('./obj.js');
```

in both `app.js` and `mymodule.js`. And then in obj.js:

```
module.exports = {one : 1};
```